# Hive 0.10 - hiveconf values with space in between

Tags: java, hive

I use my query with hiveconf to load a dynamic value as below.

PRD_CODE -> dynamic value (like A, A or B, A or C , or A or B or C, A or C)

Hence I form the syntax like:
case A or B or C: 
`(PRD_CODE = 'A' OR PRD_CODE = 'B' OR PRD_CODE = 'C')`, in my java code and pass this as  a hiveconf as below.

```
hive -hivconf prd_codes=(PRD_CODE = 'A' OR PRD_CODE = 'B' OR PRD_CODE = 'C') --hiveconf db_name=mytestdb -f myqueries.hql;
```

But, this seems to give a wrong result. Can --hiveconf can handle values with space? If not, how to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

In your query write

```
...
where PRD_CODE IN ${hiveconf:prd_codes)
...
```

and then from hive CLI

```
hive --hiveconf "prd_codes=('A', 'B', 'C')" --hiveconf db_name=mytestdb -f myqueries.hql
```